# How to install an AFM font on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, adobe-photoshop

Installing TTF fonts in Windows XP is easy (through Control Panel), but I was given an AFM font by a designer as part of the package he prepared to be viewed on Adobe Photoshop.

Control Panel's `Install New Font` doesn't see `.afm` files when prompting with the selection dialog box.

How do I make my Photoshop CS3 see those fonts?

Answer (score 2):

If you only received an `.afm` file, it's useless to you as it is.  It's an [Adobe Font Metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Adobe_Font_Metrics.2C_Adobe_Composite_Font_Metrics.2C_Adobe_Multiple_Font_Metrics) file -- it only contains a Type 1 font's basic description and metrics.  To actually make use of the font you also need the glyph data, normally in a `.pfa` or `.pfb` file.

If you also received a `.pfa` file, then you've also got the glyph data, but you'll need to find a way to convert the ASCII `.pfa` and `.afm` files into binary `.pfb` and `.pfm` files that Windows can use.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can not install .pfa files so what you can do is, download onlinefontconvertor and use to convert .pfa files to .pfb which is said to be recognized by windows(This tool also generates a .afm file along with .pfb file)